# How can I use jdk 7 JLayer in JAXX instead of jxlayer api?

Tags: java

I know that [JAXX](http://jaxx.nuiton.org) uses [jxlayer](https://java.net/projects/jxlayer) API for validation.

I would like to use instead the jdk 7 JLayer API. Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a feature of the project (See [feature 3468](https://forge.nuiton.org/issues/3468)).

I tried to make this work, but there is still some issues in BlockingLayerUI, the event are not catch...

I will try to make this work soon and then make a new release of the project.

Please feel free to use our [mailing-list](https://ml.nuiton.org/cgi-bin/mailman/listinfo/jaxx-users) if you have more questions around the project.

Comment: Ok, so still not possible. Do you have any timeline about the next release ?

Comment: I hope this week!